# When does the greedy algorithm fail?

Tags: algorithms

Is there any generalized rule to decide if applying greedy algorithm on a problem will yield optimal solution or not? For example - some of the popular algorithm problems like the ‘Coin Change’ problem and the 'Traveling Salesman' problem can not be solved optimally from greedy approach.

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend:

From [Greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm):

> They [greedy algorithms] are ideal only for problems which have 'optimal substructure'.

From [optimal substructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure):

> [A] problem is said to have optimal substructure if an optimal solution can be constructed efficiently from optimal solutions of its subproblems....
.

Comment: This question (and walpen's comment-answer) feel like they would be a better fit for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Answer (score 6):

Greedy algorithms do not find optimal solutions for **any** nontrivial optimization problem. That is the reason why optimization is a whole field of scientific research and there are tons of different optimization algorithms for different categories of problems.

Moreover, "greedy algorithms" is only a category of optimization algorithms, for a given problem, there can be lots of different greedy algorithms, so it does not make much sense to ask *"if applying greedy algorithm on a problem will yield optimal solution"*. What makes sense could be to ask "if applying **a specific** greedy algorithm" will always yield to an optimal solution, or to ask if for a given problem an "optimal" greedy algorithm exists (or not). Typically, there is no "optimal" greedy algorithm when a given optimization problem has local maxima which are not the global maximum, because a greedy algorithm will get stuck when it reaches such a local maximum.